# http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/ not connected

Tags: django, django-models, scheduled-tasks

I defined a function and when I use schedule, I don't have access to the admin page and other pages through http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/. I have a blank page.But my program works properly and i try on localhost
my code:

def search():

.

.

.

schedule.every(1).minutes.do(search)

while True:

```
schedule.run_pending()

time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Is the `while True:` loop running in the main thread? If so that would be blocking and Django wouldn't be able to respond to requests. Otherwise if that's not the problem can you send logs of the running program?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes, exactly while True: loop running in the main thread. When the function definition is finished, the while True: loop  will start What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: @sebastianjoe did you create a superuser?

Comment: yes i did. But this function dont need to login_required